# Why does my flash drive get much hotter in Linux than in Windows?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, flash

I have noticed that a flash drive that is just sitting idle in my laptop gets very hot while I am booted into Linux.  But when I boot in Windows in the same laptop, it stays cool unless I'm reading/writing with it, and after the operation is done, it cools off again.  Why would this be?

I'm running Linux Mint 19.3 with the 5.3.0-59-generic kernel, and the drive's filesystem is NTFS.  While in Linux, the drive stays hot unless I put the laptop to sleep.  I think it affects many flash drives I use, and I think it occurs on more than just this laptop.  I have a Raspberry Pi with a flash drive that gets very hot too, so many it's something that Linux is doing?

Comment: For many drives, you can use ```sudo smartctl -a /dev/yourssd``` to check how many data was written and read to / from a drive. Run this tool twice - once right after startup and once after your SSD became hot - and append its output to your question.

Comment: Does this also happens if you do not mount the partition on the drive?

Comment: I couldn't get smartctl to work.  I'm getting: `sudo smartctl -d auto /dev/sda
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-5.3.0-59-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

/dev/sda: Unknown USB bridge [0x0781:0x5583 (0x100)]
Please specify device type with the -d option.

Use smartctl -h to get a usage summary
`

Comment: ```/dev/sda``` is probably not your SSD, but an SDcard reader or sth. similar. Look out for devices like ```/dev/nvme0``` or check ```findmnt```, ```sudo blkid``` or if you run LVM2 ```sudo pvdisplay```

Answer (score 0):

Your Linux distro may be accessing it more than it should be, could be normal for that specific setup, or could be a bug accidentally causing it to be in use when not.

Comment: Is there any way I can profile it to find out why it's being accessed, and how much?